# Core Data - Segue doesn't work unless inserting new object

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Bit of an odd question, hopefully I can explain it. I'm adding objects in a method using:

```
Objects *object = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Objects" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]];
object.name = @"Whatever";
```

When I try to send it over to the ViewController (to load up into a table) with:

```
ViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
vc.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

in the prepareForSegue method, the only way it works is if I add:

```
Objects *object = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Objects" inManangedObjectContext:vc.managedObjectContext];
```

at the end. So I have to add a new entry in the segue for everything to send without errors?

The error without that line is:

```
NSRangeException', reason: [_PFBatchFaultingArray objectAtIndex:]: index(1) beyond bounds (1)
```

All help is appreciated :)

Comment: It doesn't look like you are passing the object, but instead passing a managed object context. How do you try to retrieve the object from that moc in the new view controller?

Comment: How is the managed object context created? Is it being shared between multiple things? Is it using thread confinement or queue confinement? How is the child view controller getting objects/an object from the context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a public property to your receiving view controller...

In ViewController.h

```
   #import "Objects.h"
```

and

```
   @property (nonatomic, strong) Objects *receivingObject;
```

Then in your `prepareForSegue` method include this line...

```
   vc.receivingObject = object;
```

---

**UPDATE**: with thanks to [Hal Mueller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/719690/hal-mueller)

Remove the line of code...

```
   vc.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

In the case that you need to obtain the `NSManagedObjectContext` in your destination view controller, you can use this line of code...

```
   NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.receivingObject.managedObjectContext;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Remember not to fall into the trap of public properties for both the Object and the MOC. The Object instance that your VC is working with knows its Managed Object Context. When you make @andrewbuilder's change, delete the .managedObjectContext property on the VC.

Comment: It's still giving an error of: +entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext etc. but it's a great kick off point for me. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Happy to help. Great to see you try to work the rest out yourself. If you do become stuck, it may be worth starting a new question and providing a little more information about how your view controllers are set out - for example - you have a table view controller (e.g. master) and are sending the `Objects *object` to a view controller (e.g. detail), and would like to achieve... etc. Good luck.